# I need to set autorepair to a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which have thousands of data. I want to set auto repair to the table . Will mysql support auto repair ? What is the syntax

Comment: See [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/)

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to repairing and checking tables, MySQL offers two options:

1. The MySQL distribution ships with a tool called "[myisamchk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html),"
   designed specifically to check and repair MyISAM tables (the default
   table type used by MySQL). This tool can scan your databases,
   identify problems, optimize tables for faster lookup, and optionally
   repair corrupted tables. The myisamchk tool is invoked from the
   command line.
2. In addition to the tool above, MySQL also allows you check and
   repair tables using SQL commands. The CHECK TABLE, [REPAIR TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html), and
   OPTIMIZE TABLE commands can be used on a running MySQL server and
   need to be entered through a MySQL client.

   > Eg: REPAIR [NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG | LOCAL] TABLE
   >       tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
   >       [QUICK] [EXTENDED] [USE_FRM]

Most of the time, it's preferable to use myisamchk because it is significantly faster than using SQL commands.

Concerning the "auto" part of the repairing, I suggest not to make a habit from repairing tables.
Sounds to me like you'r looking for a pump to remove water from a leak. Would the obvious thing not be to fix the leak and cause of the problem?

Remove some memory heavy functions or upgrade your server. Relying on a script or something else to auto-repair corrupted tables is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
   REPAIR TABLE `table_Name`
```

there are some option available with repair Keyword you can check [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html) according to your requirement .

Comment: Any comments on this query , Not sure it will work # mysqlcheck --debug-info -u root -p --auto-repair -c -o databasename

Comment: Repair table works for MyISAM,ARCHIVE,CSV tables only and we use it only when our table corrupted.